# Perl system command not acting as a normal prompt

Tags: linux, perl, scripting, grep

I am trying to modify a perl script to comment out all lines matching some pattern. In normal command prompt, here is the line I'm trying to add:

```
grep -lIRZ --exclude="*\.svn*" "pattern" . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e 's/.*pattern.*/\/\/&/g'
```

Here it is in the context of the perl script:

```
my $rmcmd = "grep -lIRZ --exclude=\"*\\.svn*\" \"pattern\" . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e 's/.*pattern.*/\\/\\/&/g'";
runcmd($rmcmd);
...
sub runcmd {
    my @cmd = @_;
    print "Running: @cmd\n";
    system(@cmd);
    # Get  status from system
    my $ret = $? >> 8; 

    if ($ret) {  
        print "-E- command completed with error code $ret.\n"; 
        exit(1); 
    }
    return ($ret);
}
```

Everything works properly when run from a command prompt, but the script running the same command always crashes.

What is being done differently and how can I fix it?

Comment: (1) Please post exact error you get. (2) Please print and post the value of `$rmcmd` - ideally, both via `print` and Perl debugger. (3) The correct solution is to re-write that entire complicated pipe as Perl code.

Comment: (1)The exact error is: -E- command completed with error code 1.
<br/>
(2)The print function returns: grep -lIRZ --exclude="*\.svn*" "dlclose" . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e 's/.*dlclose.*/\/\/&/g'
<br/>
(3)I am new to perl and runcmd was already defined in the script. What is the proper way to pipe in Perl code? Can you give me some references?

Comment: why are you not doing it all in Perl ? you are making your code not portable.

Comment: This Perl script already exists and is used to executes the nightly builds. I am only adding this one operation. Also, runcmd is already a function of the existing script that I am calling.

Comment: A better question would be "how do I write this in Perl?"

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me - with perl 5.10.1 on Ubuntu - after I reinserted the missing semicolon at the end of the $rmcmd = .. line.

Comment: Works for me aswell on Ubuntu.